# Dual boot Win8/Fedora19

Tags: linux, fedora

I just installed Fedora 19 (gnome, 64 bit), in addition to my Windows 8 installation. But when I start the computer, it goes straight to windows, not providing any option to boot into Fedora. How do I boot into Fedora?

Comment: Does your Win8 system boot via the UEFI bootloader?  Have you disabled UEFI secure boot?  Since I assume this is a UEFI system, look in the efi partition from windows and see if there is a 'fedora' directory.

Answer (score 1):

The windows 8 is configured by the bcdedit command:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709667%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

EasyBCD is a GUI that helps in configuring the windows boot loader, and you can find an answer to similiar question right here:
https://superuser.com/questions/499617/how-can-i-add-linux-to-the-new-windows-8-boot-manager

Answer (score 0):

And does GRUB appear during the boot? (screen where you can switch to what system do you want to boo)
 If yes, did you switch to Fedora?
 If GRUB doesn't appearing during booting process, something went wrong during installation.
Try to better describe your problem, we will can determine what is wrong...

Comment: GRUB does not appear. The computer just boots straight into windows. I again installed Fedora, and it appears successful, but upon boot still no GRUB.

Comment: I don't know. I never had problem like this one.
Maybe you can try this tutorial: http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2013/02/06/how-to-dual-boot-fedora-18-and-windows-8-on-one-hdd-with-grub-installed-in-a-pbr/